# Simple software for a download-by-link portal

Tags: open-source, javascript, encryption

I search a simple software for a download-by-link portal

I like the concept of mega.nz, with its client-side-encryption and the password in the HTML Anchor.

My Requirements are:

- Client-Side-Encryption (Key should be derived from password and SMS Token)
- SMS-Token
- server has zero-knowledge (e.g. password is in HTML Anchor)

The software could be a self-hosted JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found **Firefox Send**, its meets all my critieria.

> Send use 128-bit AES-GCM encryption via the Web Crypto API to encrypt
>   files in the browser before uploading them to the server. The code is
>   in app/keychain.js.

- Live https://send.firefox.com/
- Code: https://github.com/mozilla/send
- Encryption: https://github.com/mozilla/send/blob/master/docs/encryption.md